AutoTrigger to launch an action
I have a PowerShell script that monitors a folder to detect the creation of new PDF files and automatically triggers an action to print them. However, I want to avoid having the script running continuously, and I can't use Task Scheduler because the server restarts daily, which causes all scheduled tasks to be deleted.
I'm looking for a solution that allows the script to run automatically only when a new PDF file is created, without it running continuously. I also need an alternative that survives the server's daily restarts and can auto-trigger the script without manual intervention or constant supervision.

Consider the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher object.
Noah Peltier provides a good example of this on gist.github.com
$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path  = "C:\temp"

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher  -EventName Created  -Action {

$Object  = "{0} was  {1} at {2}" -f $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath,
            $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType,
            $Event.TimeGenerated
            $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath

  
############################ Get the last file in the directory and pull its contents 
$filepath = "C:\temp"
$filename = (get-content $filepath | sort CreationTime -Descending | select -last 1).Name
$Join = Join-Path -path $filepath -ChildPath $filename
$content = Get-Content -Raw $join | out-string

############################ Send the message
$EmailParams = @{
    credential = Import-CliXml -Path 'C:\temp\cred.xml' # this needs to be stored prior with "Get-Credential | Export-CliXml -Path C:\path\cred.xml"
    From = "email@gmail.com"
    To = "email@gmail.com"
    Subject = $Object
    Body = $content
    SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Port = "587"
    }
  Send-MailMessage @EmailParams -UseSsl
}

